# Ordenar um array Multidimensional por coluna c#

Tags: c#

Tenho um array multidimensional:

```
string[,] classificacao = new string[20, 2];
```

e que tem os seguintes inputs:

```
classificação[0,0]="Hamilton"; //ISTO É O NOME DO JOGADOR

classificação[0,1]="20"; //ISTO A SUA PONTUAÇÃO

classificação[1,0] = "Vettel";

classificação[1,1]="34";
```

Entre outros

Como posso ordenar por ordem decrescente pela coluna da pontuação sem perder o nome do respetivo jogador?

Ou seja:

```
Vettel - 34

Hamilton - 20
```

Comment: Pode começar ver o [tour]. Depois pode ir ao [help]. Se ainda quiser se aprofundar vá ao [meta].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O .NET Framework não tem funções para ordenar arrays multidimensionais diretamente - as funções de ordenação funcionam principalmente para arrays *jagged*. Uma solução é você converter o seu array para *jagged*, ordená-lo, e depois convertê-lo de volta. O código abaixo mostra um exemplo disso:

```
class PtStackOverflow_209128
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string[,] classificacao = new string[4, 2];
        classificacao[0, 0] = "Hamilton"; //ISTO É O NOME DO JOGADOR
        classificacao[0, 1] = "104"; //ISTO A SUA PONTUAÇÃO
        classificacao[1, 0] = "Vettel";
        classificacao[1, 1] = "129";
        classificacao[2, 0] = "Bottas";
        classificacao[2, 1] = "75";
        classificacao[3, 0] = "Räikkönen";
        classificacao[3, 1] = "67";

        var jagged = ToJagged(classificacao);
        Array.Sort(jagged, (i1, i2) => int.Parse(i2[1]) - int.Parse(i1[1]));
        classificacao = ToRectangular(jagged);
        for (int i = 0; i < classificacao.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < classificacao.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", classificacao[i, j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static T[][] ToJagged<T>(T[,] array)
    {
        int height = array.GetLength(0), width = array.GetLength(1);
        T[][] jagged = new T[height][];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            T[] row = new T[width];
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                row[j] = array[i, j];
            }
            jagged[i] = row;
        }
        return jagged;
    }
    static T[,] ToRectangular<T>(T[][] array)
    {
        int height = array.Length, width = array[0].Length;
        T[,] rect = new T[height, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            T[] row = array[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                rect[i, j] = row[j];
            }
        }
        return rect;
    }
}
```

(As funções de conversão foram copiadas [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232465/751090) do SOen).

Comment: pelo que estou a ver esse código não da para incorporar num botao; é que eu estou a trabalhar em Windows Form

Comment: @TiagoPereira dá sim para incorporar em um botão ou qualquer outra ação que é pertinente o uso desse código.

Comment: já é um começo, mas eu já copiei esse código para o meu botão e existem métodos que n são reconhecidos

Comment: @carlosfigueira consegui adaptar o código ao meu programa e funcionou lindamente, embora n perceba nada do código, obg na mesma

Answer (score 3):

Arrays ??? Faz uma classe meu garoto !

```
public class Classificacao
{
    public Classificacao()
    {

    }

    public Classificacao(String Piloto, Int32 Pontuacao)
    {
        this.Piloto = Piloto;
        this.Pontuacao = Pontuacao;
    }

    public String Piloto { get; set; }

    public Int32 Pontuacao { get; set; }
}
```

Depois para Ordenar, Lambda !

```
        List<Classificacao> Classif = new List<Classificacao>();
        Classif.Add(new Classificacao("Hamilton", 20));
        Classif.Add(new Classificacao("Vettel", 34));
        Classif.OrderBy(p => p.Pontuacao);

        foreach (Classificacao c in Classif)
        { 
            //faz alguma ação com seu List Ordenado
        }
```

Comment: na verdade no meu programa eu tenho um array com 20 jogadores, eu aleatoriamente ordeno o array, para saber o 1 classificado e por ai adiante, e consoante isso, o 1ª lugar ira receber 10 pontos, o segundo 5 e continua...; e por essa resolução não penso que vá fazer o que queira

Comment: Altere a linha Classif.OrderBy(p => p.Pontuacao); para Classif.OrderByDescending(p => p.Pontuacao); Assim ele ordenará de forma decrescente, por pontuação

Comment: Concordo que uma classe é melhor solução, mas, a pergunta não foi para essa solução, desculpas, mas, acho injusto.

Comment: Injusto em que sentido ?

Comment: A sua resposta @JulioSoares responde talvez uma outra pergunta é uma excelente resposta, mas, não o que a pergunta fez. Se poderia até colocar duas soluções e essa sendo a melhor, mas, deveria então conter uma resposta sobre `array` multidimensional ... Há a culpa não é sua só foi uma indicação.

Comment: Eu concordo com o @VirgilioNovic. Esta resposta resolve o problema principal (ordenar os dados), mas não o faz da forma que foi pedido.

Comment: Realmente @VirgilioNovic, a resposta não resolve a questão como pedida mas sugere para quem tiver uma questão similar a possibilidade de decidir se mantém os array ou parte para uma nova abordagem. As vezes, pode dar uma luz !.. Mas vou focar mais nas questões nas próximas respostas... Abraços !